# jquery ajaxComplete equivalent in axios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, axios

Started learning axios and I'm loving it!

Quick question, could not find an answer for it, maybe there is non.

In jQuery ajax there is a method called ajaxComplete, I was wandering if there is an equivalent in axios?

Answer (score 0):

axios uses promises. You can use

```
axios.get(url,[options]).then(res=>{
/* hande it here */
})
```

Check out how js promises work if you do not have a basic knowledge https://web.dev/promises/

For global handling axios event this may help https://auralinna.blog/post/2019/global-http-request-and-response-handling-with-the-axios-interceptor/

Comment: I mean, there is an XHR request that is being called by the site (wordpess plugin), I want to do X after this request was completed. In ajax it is simple, I can use .ajaxComplete(), check the XHR url and thats it. Is there something similar in axios?

Comment: https://auralinna.blog/post/2019/global-http-request-and-response-handling-with-the-axios-interceptor/

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. jQuery's `$.ajax` has a function build in where it fires an event when a request has been finished. This is the `ajaxComplete` event.

Axios does not have such behavior, but you could build your own with the [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) interface. Or / and assume that there is a method `axiosSuccess` on the `document` and call that.

```
const axiosGet = async url => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url)
    const axiosSuccessEvent = new CustomEvent('axiossuccess', {
      detail: { url, response }
    })
    document.dispatchEvent(axiosSuccessEvent)
    if (typeof document.axiosSuccess === 'function') {
      document.axiosSuccess({ url, response })
    }
    return response
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

And then listen for your own event on the document.

```
document.addEventListener('axiossuccess', event => {
  const { detail } = event
  const { url, response } = detail
  console.log(url, response)
})

document.axiosSuccess = ({ url, response }) => {
  console.log(url, response)
}

axiosGet('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998921/')
```